# Is there a way to dynamically change the attributes (speed, diameter, etc) of a custom pedestrian type?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to make my pedestrian, which is a custom pedestrian type, to be assigned a different diameter and/-or comfortable speed depending on which block and process the pedestrian is currently in. The Pedestrian API has a function for that, but it is not applicable on a custom pedestrian type.

Answer (score 0):

The ped API *should* be available on your custom type.

The likely issue is that you did not actually create it as a custom ped agent (just as a normal-type agent that is being sent through a ped process).

Check that your ped type has "Use in flowcharts as" set to `Pedestrian`, *and* that your PedSource is creating agents of that type (and not of type `Agent`).